# How to build embeddable Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, embeddable

I am wondering how to build embeddable Python for Windows. Could not find any info or build configuration for that particular package.

Reason I ask is that I could use the same variant for Mac and Linux.

Comment: what do you mean build embeddable? You can build Python and embed it yourself, there's no notion of an embeddable build AFAIK.

Comment: If you look at the Windows download page, there is a package called embeddable Python. This one.

Comment: One thing I should note is that you have to include (at least a part of) Python stdlib, including Python code, in your embedded version, because the interpreter actively uses things like codecs and import machinery internally.

Comment: @9000 yes, specifically [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40634115/which-standard-library-modules-are-required-to-run-the-python-3-5-interpreter/40740974#40740974) in `3.5` from what I had found out (On Ubuntu, at least). Could you give us the link you're talking about, abergmeier?

Comment: See https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/ - _Windows x86-64 embeddable zip file_

Comment: Looks like it's described [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pythonengineering/2016/04/26/cpython-embeddable-zip-file/) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37633550/python-embeddable-zip). I don't see any useful information for building that version in the [Windows build readme](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/PCbuild/readme.txt) or the [Windows build script](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/PCbuild/build.bat).

Comment: If you want to embed Python in your application on Unix, you should probably look at the Python documentation section on "Extending and Embedding the Python Interpreter", particularly [this bit](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html#compiling-and-linking-under-unix-like-systems).

Answer (score 7):

Recently, I had to build an embeddable zip for 64bit Python 3.5.6 (since the official download page doesn't offer them for Python greater than 3.5.4), here are the steps.

#### Prerequisites (one-time install)

Install

1. git
2. TortoiseSVN
3. Visual Studio C++ Build Tools 2015 (you may need version 2017 when building latest Python versions)<sup>1</sup>
4. If you haven't `Sphinx` installed, install it and add `sphinx-build` to `PATH`<sup>2</sup>:

   ```
   > python -m pip install --user sphinx
   > set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Users\jenkins\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\Scripts
   ```
5. If you haven't `blurb` installed, install it, add `blurb` to `PATH` if necessary (if you've done the previous step, you already have the correct `PATH`):

   ```
   > python -m pip install --user blurb
   > set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Users\jenkins\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\Scripts
   ```

#### Configure build environment

1. Clone CPython repo. Here, I clone only the tag I need:

   ```
   > git clone --depth 1 --branch v3.5.6 https://github.com/python/cpython
   ```
2. In the repo dir, generate `NEWS` file<sup>3, 4</sup>:

   ```
   > blurb merge -f Misc\NEWS
   ```

#### Build

Now you can trigger the build:

```
> Tools\msi\buildrelease.bat -x64 --skip-nuget --test testout
```

Replace `-x64` with `-x32` if you target the 32bit arch. `--skip-nuget` will omit building the MSI installer. `--test testout` will trigger installer tests; you can skip them if you want.

Once the build finishes, check for build artifact `PCbuild\amd64\en-us\python-3.5.6-embed-amd64.zip`. This is your embeddable zip.

After the build succeeds for the first time, you can skip the doc build in future builds for further speedup as long as the doc build artifacts remain in repo:

```
> Tools\msi\buildrelease.bat -x64 --skip-doc --skip-nuget --test testout
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Make sure you select "Custom" in the VC++ Build Tools installer and check all the options; otherwise, you may get build errors like `The code execution cannot proceed because ucrtbased.dll was not found` etc. I'm no Windows expert by all means, just installed everything possible to get rid of the errors.

<sup>2</sup> Looking at the `buildrelease.bat` help, it seems like you can skip the doc build with `--skip-doc` flag, but when using that, I got the error

```
"C:\Users\jenkins\projects\cpython\Tools\msi\bundle\releaselocal.wixproj" 
(Rebuild target) (1) ->
  "C:\Users\jenkins\projects\cpython\Tools\msi\doc\doc.wixproj" (Rebuild target) (7) ->
(Link target) ->
  C:\Users\jenkins\projects\cpython\Tools\msi\doc\doc_files.wxs(8): error 
LGHT0103: The system cannot find the file 'python356.chm'. [C:\Users\jenkins\projects\cpython\Tools\msi\doc\doc.wixproj]
```

and the build aborts with an error. If you manage to circumvent this without an initial doc build (so the doc files are available in the build dir), you can skip `Sphinx` install.

<sup>3</sup> Otherwise, I get the build error

```
"C:\Users\jenkins\projects\cpython\Tools\msi\bundle\releaselocal.wixproj" (Rebuild target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\jenkins\projects\cpython\Tools\msi\exe\exe.wixproj" (Rebuild target) (8) ->
  C:\Users\jenkins\projects\cpython\Tools\msi\exe\exe_files.wxs(9): error 
LGHT0103: The system cannot find the file '!(bindpath.src)Misc\NEWS'. [C:\Users\jenkins\projects\cpython\Tools\msi\exe\exe.wixproj]
```

<sup>4</sup> You can replace the command with an appropriate `make` invocation, but I was too lazy to decipher the `Doc\Makefile`. After all, the news won't land in the embeddable zip anyway; this is only to make the `buildrelease.bat` happy.

Comment: `LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'pgort.lib' [\Python-3.8.3\PCbuild\pythoncore.vcxproj]` any idea why + how to fix?