# How to make embedded Python 3.10 work with Windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, pip, embedded

I have found here [an old Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42280553/how-to-build-embeddable-python)  - but now version 3.10 was released. I could unzip the embeddedPython ZIP ( [here](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.10.0/python-3.10.0-embed-win32.zip) ). Moreover I followed teh HOW-TO for pip install manually (  [3](https://www.activestate.com/resources/quick-reads/how-to-install-pip-on-windows/) )
.
All the Libraries for modules (in my case I need the `requests` module) where also in my Directory `c:\users\walter\Documents\python-3.10.0-embed-win32`.  But when I let run a `py-script` the module `requests` is not found. You should know that I let the Pyton run in Delphi's RAD-Studio Berlin `Python4Delphi`( [YouTube-How_TO](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hjY6lBgrHhM) ). It works fine, but the `pip`installed module `requests` is not found.
What kind of `PATHS` need to be defined for embedded Python?  When I use the registrated Python INSTALLER, it works fine. But I what to add the embedded version into my MSI.

EDIT: Here is an other same good reference. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7472436/add-a-directory-to-python-sys-path-so-that-its-included-each-time-i-use-python/57657501#57657501)
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had to set the sys.path like this in my script, where relative to my `py`script there my site-packages.

```
   import sys 
   sys.path.append(os.path.join( 'C:/', 'Users', 'Walter', 'Documents','python-3.10.0-embed-amd64', 'lib', 'site-packages'))
   import requests
```

works fine now.